# spring boot application would not statring from cmd how to start it from cmd

Tags: java, spring-boot, executable-jar

The following error occurs when running spring boot project from cmd

I want to run my spring boot project from cmd but i can't understand what is the problem with it why it is not working, why it is not running. when i run my spring boot project using inteliij IDE it run without any issue and error but i is not running when i am tring to run it through cmd using the following command : java -jar target/myProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

```
2019-02-01 15:24:31.083  INFO 15164 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/lfms]   : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-02-01 15:24:31.083  INFO 15164 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7899 ms
2019-02-01 15:24:31.314  INFO 15164 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2019-02-01 15:24:31.319  INFO 15164 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-02-01 15:24:31.320  INFO 15164 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-02-01 15:24:31.321  INFO 15164 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-02-01 15:24:31.321  INFO 15164 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-02-01 15:24:31.444  WARN 15164 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileUtil' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/tecor/TL/lfms/target/lfms-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/lfms/util/FileUtil.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2019-02-01 15:24:33.679  INFO 15164 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-02-01 15:24:33.706  INFO 15164 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-02-01 15:24:33.715 ERROR 15164 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileUtil' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/tecor/TL/lfms/target/lfms-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/lfms/util/FileUtil.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1238) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1137) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at com.lfms.Application.main(Application.java:19) [classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [lfms-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [lfms-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [lfms-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [lfms-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:170) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1230) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.update(StreamReader.java:218) ~[snakeyaml-1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.ensureEnoughData(StreamReader.java:176) ~[snakeyaml-1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.ensureEnoughData(StreamReader.java:171) ~[snakeyaml-1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.peek(StreamReader.java:126) ~[snakeyaml-1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.scanToNextToken(ScannerImpl.java:1177) ~[snakeyaml-1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:287) ~[snakeyaml-1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:227) ~[snakeyaml-1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseImplicitDocumentStart.produce(ParserImpl.java:195) ~[snakeyaml-1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158) ~[snakeyaml-1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:148) ~[snakeyaml-1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:107) ~[snakeyaml-1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:139) ~[snakeyaml-1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:524) ~[snakeyaml-1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:452) ~[snakeyaml-1.23.jar!/:na]
        at com.lfms.util.FileUtil.<clinit>(FileUtil.java:37) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.io.PushbackInputStream.ensureOpen(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.UnicodeReader.init(UnicodeReader.java:92) ~[snakeyaml-1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.UnicodeReader.read(UnicodeReader.java:124) ~[snakeyaml-1.23.jar!/:na]
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.update(StreamReader.java:183) ~[snakeyaml-1.23.jar!/:na]
        ... 46 common frames omitted
```

> FileUtil file code that show's how it was accessing application.yml file properties

```
Yaml yml = new Yaml();
        Map<String, Map<String, Object>> ymlProperties = yml.load(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("application.yml"));
```

Comment: How did you package your jar? `mvn package`?

Comment: @ngueno mvn clean package install

Comment: Try `mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: its there a yml file in you resources or project directory , like configuration file

Comment: Probably can't read correctly the ressource. Is the yaml file inside the jar ? also, how is the path setted in the project ?

Comment: Can you share the code that's trying to read the YAML in `FileUtil`?

Comment: From exception probably issue may be of configuration file .yml plz check yml file inside jar or not.

Comment: @SunimalS.KMalkakulage   yes there is an application.yml file

Comment: @Asoub yes i check in jar file there is the application.yml file exist

Comment: @DHARMENDRASINGH i check it it is in the jar

Comment: @AndyWilkinson ya sure im updating my question and adding fileutil code that accessing application.yml file

Comment: @SofoGial it giving same error as above i mention

Comment: Instead of using file name in getSystemResourceAsStream() use FileInputStream object.

Comment: @DHARMENDRASINGH please provide me an example or sample code of what you want to tell me

Comment: Why are you loading `application.yml` yourself? Spring Boot will do that for you automatically.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson no i am not loading it myself,  spring boot do it automatically

Comment: yml.load(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(new FileInputStream("application.yml"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you package a Spring Boot application as an executable jar and launch it, the `ClassLoader` structure changes. As a result, the system class loader cannot find your `application.yml` file. Rather than using `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(String)` you should use `FileUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(String)`. This will ensure that you use the class loader that loaded your `FileUtil` class to read the `application.yml` file.

Comment: thank you for your answer it helps me , thank you so much